# Proving a quartic has exactly one positive real solution

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now :

> Let $a\geq0$.
> Show the following polynomial has exactly one positive root for all $k\geq 0$: where k is a real
> $$f(a)=k^2a^4 + 2ka^3 -(k^3+k^2-1)a^2-2k^2a-k$$
> More over prove that the corresponding root $a_0 \in \mathopen[\sqrt{k-1},\sqrt{k}\mathclose]$ for $k\geq 1$

**My take:**

First of all we can easily prove there exists a positive root $\alpha$ for $f(a)$ using IVT.

Then i computed the first and second derivative:
$$f'(a)=4k^2a^3+6ka^2-2(k^3+k^2-1)a-2k^2$$
$$f''(a)=12k^2a^2+12ak-2(k^3+k^2-1)$$
also $f''(a)$  is increasing over all the positive reals because $12k^2\geq 0$ and $12k\geq0$

$$f''(a)=0\Leftrightarrow a=-\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{\sqrt{3(3k^2+3k^3+1)}}{6k}$$
but $$a \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 3k^3+k^2-2\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow k\geq 0.755$$
so if $k < 0.755$ then  $f''(a)>0$ for all $a\geq0$  which means $f'(a)$ is strictly increasing over the positive the reals.

Also since $$f'(0)=-2k^2\le 0$$and $$\lim_{a\to\infty} f'(a)=+\infty$$
then by the intermediate value theorem there exists a positive real number $a_0$ such that $f'(a_0)=0$

*Case 1*:

$\alpha \in \mathopen[0,a_0\mathclose]$

Suppose there exists another  positive real $\beta$ such that $f(\beta)=0$

Then by Rolle's theorem there exists a $c\in \mathopen]\alpha,\beta[$ such that $f'(c)=0$

*Case 1-a*

if $\beta \in \mathopen[0,a_0\mathclose[$ then c is in the same interval so by montony of $f'$ we get $0=f'(c)<f'(a_0)=0$ which is a contradiction

*Case 1-b*

if $\beta \in \mathopen[a_0,+\infty\mathclose[$ then $c\in \mathopen[0,+\infty\mathclose[$

but here it's possible to find $f'(c)=0$  for $c=a_0$  since $a_0$ lies in  $\mathopen[0,+\infty\mathclose[$

While plotting it in Desmos it looks like for all $k\ge 0$  we have $a_0<\alpha$ which would solve the problem since for the second case  where $\alpha \in \mathopen[a_0,+\infty\mathclose[$,
Rolle's theorem applies directly but i can't prove it , and even then i have to prove the same proposition for $k\geq 0.755$ which i am unable to do .

Thanks  in advance for any help.

Comment: This is false, if $k=0$, $f(x)=x^2$, no prositive roots. Btw, why you wrote $f(a)$ instead of $f(x)$ or $f(t)$?

Comment: oh i'm sorry by positive root i meant a=0 is also included , I also wrote f(a) because that's how it was written in the exercise it's just notation after all.

Comment: Is $k$ an integer? Or at least $k \geq 1$ so that $ \sqrt{k-1}$ makes sense?

Comment: I think it's ok now i apologize  i forgot to specify the interval of k for the second question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that a positive root exists and is unique:

For any $k>0,$ there is exactly one sign change in the sequence of polynomial's coefficients:
$$f(a)=\underbrace{k^2}_+a^4 \underbrace{+ 2k}_+a^3 \underbrace{-(k^3+k^2-1)}_\pm a^2\underbrace{-2k^2}_-a\underbrace{-k}_- $$
By [Descarte's rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), the polynomial has exactly one positive real root for any $k>0.$

I have doubts that the root lies in $[\sqrt{k-1},\sqrt{k}],$ because
$$f(\sqrt{k})=-k^3<0,$$
but
$$\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}f(a)=\infty.$$